# How to fix horizontal label issue using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show the horizontal label in single line. But it is coming with two line.
How to show the form label with single line?

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="mt32">Bootstrap 4 Horizontal Form</h2>

  <form class="mt32" action="#">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="fname"
              placeholder="First name"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="lname"
              placeholder="Last name"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-2">Sports</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="sportsname"
              placeholder="Sports name"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-2">School Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="sname"
              placeholder="Shcool name"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-reactiveform-validation-with-bootstrap-ewjfdm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Expecting label name in single line.

Comment: Well give them more room then ...? `<label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>` - it would at least take `col-5` in your given example, to make that element at that nesting depth wide enough to show those two words next to each other.

Comment: @CBroe: Can you edit the stackblitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The classes I had to add are as follows:

1. `text-nowrap` to the label so that the texts don't wrap
2. `align-items-end` for vertically centering the text with the inputs
3. Also added/modified some `.col` classes

Here is the: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-reactiveform-validation-with-bootstrap-sbvkj4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="mt32">Bootstrap 4 Horizontal Form</h2>
    
    <form class="mt32" action="#">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group row align-items-end">
            <label for="fname" class="control-label text-nowrap col-sm-4">First Name</label>
            <div class="col">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="fname"
                placeholder="First name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group row align-items-end">
            <label for="fname" class="control-label text-nowrap col-sm-4">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="lname"
                placeholder="Last name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group row align-items-end">
            <label for="fname" class="control-label text-nowrap col-sm-3">Sports</label>
            <div class="col">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="sportsname"
                placeholder="Sports name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group row align-items-end">
            <label for="fname" class="control-label text-nowrap col-sm-5">School Name</label>
            <div class="col">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="sname"
                placeholder="Shcool name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the col-sm-{number}, so change this section of your code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="lname"
          placeholder="Last name"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-5 pl-1 p-0 mt-2">
        Last Name
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-7 pl-0">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="lname"
          placeholder="Last name"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I modified this lines, each input and his label has to match like this:

```
      <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-5 pl-1 p-0 mt-2">

      <div class="col-sm-7 pl-0">
```

Here is all your code modified:

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="mt32">Bootstrap 4 Horizontal Form</h2>

<form class="mt32" action="#">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-4 pl-1 p-0 mt-2">
      First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8 pl-0">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="fname"
          placeholder="First name"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-5 pl-1 p-0 mt-2">
        Last Name
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-7 pl-0">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="lname"
          placeholder="Last name"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-4 pl-1 p-0 mt-2"
        >Sports</label
      >
      <div class="col-sm-8 pl-0">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="sportsname"
          placeholder="Sports name"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="control-label col-sm-5 pl-1 p-0 mt-2"
        >School Name</label
      >
      <div class="col-sm-7 pl-0">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="sname"
          placeholder="Shcool name"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```